# Did Dinosaurs have a neocortex?

Tags: genetics, evolution, dinosaurs

Did dinosaurs have a neocortex in their brains? If not, when did it come into existence?

Answer (score 3):

Dinosaurs did *not* have a neocortex - but many of them might have had something neocortex-like.

The neocortex does, in fact, appear to be [a uniquely mammalian brain structure](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3610574/).  However, [birds are dinosaurs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Info&id=8782), and although birds do not have a neocortex [they do have complex brain structures that appear to be fairly similar in function](https://www.pnas.org/content/112/11/3184).

The neocortex and analogous bird brain structures do appear to have derived from the same base, which means that somewhere after the [amniota split](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Undef&id=32524), at least some fraction of dinosaurs did in fact possess those neocortex-like structures that we still observe in birds today.

Since information about brains does not fossilize well, [we still know very little about dinosaur brains](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/scientists-reconstructed-dinosaurs-pea-sized-brain-180976211/). As such, it's not currently possible to know whether all dinosaurs had such brain structures, or if it only emerged in the group that we now know as birds.

Comment: There is some evidence for the bird structure in at least maniraptorans, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4262302/ but the issue with definition does make it weak at best.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for your time